# Relational algebra "grouping"

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Sorry for the vague question topic!

I've got a particular relational-algebra problem that has me and a couple of friends stumped.

Now, here's the question:

```
For each department, find the maximum salary of instructors in that
department. You may assume that every department has at least one
instructor.
```

I'll upload the schema as well, as a visual aide.[image]

I've worked this out to a point;

I need a relation that includes all the instructors in any department, we've got that. It's the `instructor` relation.

Out of that relation i need to 'split' it up into a per-department basis. and once I have that relation I just take the `max(salary)` and return that.

Problem is, the only way I can think of to do that is something like this:

```
π(max(salary)(σ(dept_name = x(instructor)))
```

Where x = whatever dept_name i'm looking for, but If I did it this way, then I'd have to do a new relation for every department!

How would you do it?

(Note: I just copy and paste'd the symbols from wikipedia if you want to use them in your answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My relational algebra might be a bit rusty but I think that

```
dept_name_G_{max(salary)}(
    σ_{ddept_name = idept_name}(
        ρ_{dept_name/ddept_name}(department) ⨯
        ρ_{dept_name/idept_name}(instructor)
    )
)
```

is what you seek for.

Remember that all projections are just operations on sets. The first thing you would do to 
connect the information of `department` and `instructor` is to bring the information together.
So you want to join `department` and `instructor`, basically a cross product (`⨯`):

```
department = {(depA, 100$), (depB, 200$)}
instructor = {(will, depA, 10$), (bob, depB, 20$), (will, depB, 9$)}
department ⨯ instructor = {
                            (depA, 100$, will, depA, 10$), 
                            (depA, 100$, bob, depB, 20$), 
                            ..., 
                            (depB, 200$, will, depA, 10$), 
                            ...
                          }
```

So what you would want now is to filter the tuples where the `dept_name` of the instructor equals the 
`dept_name` of the department. But you also notice that you now have a naming collision, 
namely the column `dept_name` comes up twice.

As you can't simply do `σ_{dept_name = dept_name}(department ⨯ instructor)` you need to rename at
least one of the `dept_name` fields. I renamed both for clarity which one belongs to what.

So what you now have is

```
σ_{ddept_name = idept_name}(
    ρ_{dept_name/ddept_name}(department) ⨯
    ρ_{dept_name/idept_name}(instructor)
)
```

giving you:

```
{
 (depA, 100$, will, depA, 10$), 
 (depB, 200$, bob, depB, 20$),
 (depB, 200$, will, depB, 9$)
}
```

The whole process is a [natural join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Natural_join) and can be expressed shortly with:

```
department ⋈ instructor
```

Now the final step is to project the maximum salary per department. A simple projection can't do that
but the [aggregation operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Aggregation) can:

```
{dept_name}_G_{max(salary)}(department ⋈ instructor)
```

results in

```
{
 (depA, 10$), 
 (depB, 20$)
}
```

Comment: This is pretty good! It answers my question and clears up the confusion I had between cross product and natural join. Major props for this!

Comment: @YourbrainonCompSci & nemo Natural join only returns one column for each input column name. To get the natural join having renamed both dept columns before the cross join, you have to project out one and rename the other back after the restriction. (And that rename is missing in the version at the top of the answer.) Or to get the natural join only rename one table dept and project it out after the restriction.

Comment: @YourbrainonCompSci & nemo Except that there's no MAX or GROUP in traditional relational algebra. This is essentially SQL not any typical relational algebra. Although some queries expressible with them can still be expressed without them. Like the one in the question. The assignment is much harder if you're not allowed to use them. I wonder what algebra was supposed to be used. (There are numerous.)